# scala - How does method :: works in List?

Tags: scala

I notice that List class define the method `::`, which adds an element at the beginning of the list

```
def ::(x: A): List[A]
```

Example:

```
1 :: List(2, 3) = List(2, 3).::(1) = List(1, 2, 3)
```

However, I am confused at How does scala compiler recognize such conversion? Because as far as I am concerned,

```
1 :: List(2,3)
```

should raise an `error:  :: is not a member of Int`

Do I miss something about operator definition of scala?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Methods whose names end with `:` are *right-associative*](http://Scala-Lang.Org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#infix-operations) when called using infix operator notation. I.e.

```
a foo_: b
```

is the same as

```
b.foo_:(a)
```

This rule exists specifically for the case of methods like this, which are commonly (in other languages such as Haskell and ML) operators like `:` or `::`.

Comment: Thanks ! Now it make sense. However, I manage to find corresponding content in scala docs but fail.

Comment: I added a link to the Scala Language Specification.